# Visual Studio 2015 Error code 1 On Building Cordova App for Android

Tags: android, cordova, ant, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build my First Cordova app on Visual Studio and somehow. I can't even get my app Compiled for android. I have no Idea what am I Doing Wrong.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       cmd: Command failed with exit code 1    ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp    c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ERROR building one of the platforms  1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       cmd: Command failed with exit code 1    ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp    c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\MDAVSCLI 1
```

tools for Cordova Dependency Checker tells that it's All right and every thing is Installed Correctly.

I've already created a Keystore

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -validity 10000
```

and updated my ant.properties file:

```
key.store="my-release-key.keystore "
key.alias="alias_name "
key.store.password="xxx"
key.alias.password="xxx"
```

(I tried using both absolute & relative paths but still no luck)

here is the log I'm getting

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.4
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Parsa Gachkar\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------    changeList.changedFilesIos: bower.json,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\index.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\css\index.css,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,package.json,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,build.json,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,res\native\android\ant.properties,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png,config.xml,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\NOTICE,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\android\WhitelistPlugin.java,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\whitelist.js,plugins\fetch.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\plugin.xml,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\package.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\CONTRIBUTING.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\LICENSE,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\ios\CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.h,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\RELEASENOTES.md,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\ios\CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.m,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\README.md,www\images\Parsag.jpg,www\images\20150804_195327.jpg,www\css\Roboto-Regular.ttf,www\css\B Yekan.ttf,www\css\css\ionicons.css,www\css\css\ionicons.min.css,www\css\fonts\ionicons.svg,www\css\fonts\ionicons.ttf,www\css\fonts\ionicons.eot,www\css\fonts\ionicons.woff,parsa-key.keystore,res\native\android\parsa-key.keystore
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Copied c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\native\android\ant.properties to platforms\android\ant.properties
1>  ------ Copied c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\native\android\parsa-key.keystore to platforms\android\parsa-key.keystore
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Preparing android project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' ]
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp"
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myappf45017"
1>  ------ Copied c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug "--buildConfig=c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\build.json"""
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android-SDK\Android-SDK-Full-2014-12-03-EhsanAvr.Com
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\
1>  c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\build.json
1>  Reading build config file: c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\build.json
1>  Running: c:\Users\Parsa Gachkar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b c:\Users\Parsa Gachkar\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
1>  Unzipping C:\Users\Parsa Gachkar\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to C:\Users\Parsa Gachkar\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\2m8005s69iu8v0oiejfej094b
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug "--buildConfig=c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\build.json""
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

BTW I'm trying to build it with Debug Config

anyone got this thing working? Can you explain what you have done exactly?

And no this Question is not a Duplicate of any Questions on SO, I've Already Done a research and the answers were not Useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by compiling the app manually.

My firewall was producing the issue. The Java SDK was trying to download some libraries and my firewall blocked it so Gradle wasn't able to compile and as the result my Gradle installation was corrupted. Here are the steps I took to solve this issue:

- Delete `C:\Users\Parsa Gachkar\.gradle`
- Turn off firewall or unblock Java
- Recompile

Comment: How to unblock Java?

Comment: @Krishnavrinsoft Check this [link](http://www.technipages.com/blockunblock-programs-in-windows-firewall) out ! and unblock java.exe!

Answer (score 0):

I was given the same error, but it had a different solution.

Here is my solution:

By looking to the out put message I understood the problem occurred when "build.bat" was running:

```
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c ""c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug "--buildConfig=c:\users\parsa gachkar\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\ParsasProgrammerCompanionApp\build.json""
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So I ran the "build.bat" file by CMD and it gave me more information:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No installed build tools found. Please install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
```

and when I installed build tools from Android SDK Manager the problem vanished.